# Present a viewController from collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I am extending the UICollectionView to create an empty View, I couldn't call **self.present**. Is there a better way to handle empty view? How should i handle self.present in collectionView?

```
extension UICollectionView {
    func setEmptyView() {

        let signUpButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        signUpButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSignIn), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func onSignIn() {
        let viewController = SignInController()
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    
    }
}
```

Comment: either you need to get controller as parameter or get topController to present

Comment: It's bad design to open a ViewController from View, My suggestion is to use delegate and ask UICollectionView's ViewController to handle delegate to open your SignInController(). Reason is you might find issue like rotation, statusbar and navigation bar handling etc. (Basically all which should inherited from previous view controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can present from top controller.. using this extension you will get top controller ...

```
extension UIApplication {

    class func getTopMostViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
        if var topController = keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                topController = presentedViewController
            }
            return topController
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your collection view extension

```
extension UICollectionView {
    func setEmptyView() {

        let signUpButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        signUpButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSignIn), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func onSignIn() {
        let viewController = SignInController()
        viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        UIApplication.getTopMostViewController()?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, however I am confuse this is a good way to handle empty view. or just create an collcetion view cell for it ?

Comment: there is a superb library on github ... https://github.com/Xiaoye220/EmptyDataSet-Swift

Comment: thanks, btw why it does not support push view controller